# MAUI: Namespace for restrictedcapabilities does not seem to work properly

Tags: c#, maui

To gain system wide file access for my maui Windows app I added the following in the package.appxmanifest.

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

I can't quite figure out the error message, because it's done exactly like this in the official doc.

Package.appxmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/
        foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

<Identity Name="maui-package-name-placeholder" Publisher="CN=User Name" 
    Version="0.0.0.0" />

<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="EB2B3BD9-A87D-46D5-9338-702E53F5986D" 
    PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

<Properties>
  <DisplayName>$placeholder$</DisplayName>
  <PublisherDisplayName>User Name</PublisherDisplayName>
  <Logo>$placeholder$.png</Logo>
</Properties>

<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" 
        MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" 
        MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
</Dependencies>

<Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
</Resources>

<Applications>
     <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" 
         EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
     <uap:VisualElements
          DisplayName="$placeholder$"
          Description="$placeholder$"
          Square150x150Logo="$placeholder$.png"
          Square44x44Logo="$placeholder$.png"
          BackgroundColor="transparent">
          <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="$placeholder$.png" 
            Wide310x150Logo="$placeholder$.png" Square310x310Logo="$placeholder$.png" />
          <uap:SplashScreen Image="$placeholder$.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
</Applications>

<Capabilities>
  <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Unfortunately, the following line is underlined in green and gives the following message:
<rescap:Capability

Warning message:

The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities'.
List of possible elements expected: 'CapabilityChoice' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/7'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2'
as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10' as well as 'CustomCapabilityChoice' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'CustomCapab....

Maybe someone can help me there

Comment: Maui does not target UWP; it runs on .Net 7+, targetting "Windows UI 3". See [Permissions, on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=windows). In the table, note Red "X" on Windows platform for storage-related permissions. In this case, no permission declaration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just as ToolmakerSteve said that `Maui does not target UWP; it runs on .Net 7+, targetting "Windows UI 3".`

According to the [MAUI document about the permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=windows#available-permissions), you can see that the Windows platform does not support the `StorageWrite` and `StorageRead` permission.